# How to solve ORA-01157 error?

Tags: oracle

I accidentally deleted one of Oracle DBF files, and now I receive this error .

```
ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 2 - see DBWR trace file
ORA-01110: data file 2: 'D:\T1.DBF'
```

My database instance could not be open.I searched internet and find some suggestion about using Backup to restore, but I don't have any.
Thank you guys a lot.

Comment: Take this as a lesson to set up a backup.  Hack to get your DB running [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/981464) but this won't recover any of your lost data.

Comment: Has the system been booted or is it still uup and running since deletion?  if still up and running I See several ways to recover it from memory... http://www.gunnalag.com/2014/03/24/options-to-recover-a-oracle-database-without-backup-files-or-when-accidentally-deleted-the-dbf-files-in-linux/ or https://www.pythian.com/blog/how-to-recover-deleted-oracle-datafiles-with-no-downtime/

Comment: I didn't have important information  in db, and I manualy deleted one of dbf that was created for testing not primary oracle dbf. And now just want to work with db but it is not possible. TNS is running , when I enter to sqlplus as sysdba  encounter with an idle instance that should be open, but I receive that error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the answer of my question. If we accidentally delete a DBF file database couldn't be open and it just could be mounted.

Now the solution is as follow:

1-connect as `sys as sysdba`

2-`startup mount;`

3- `alter database datafile 'D:\T1.dbf' offline drop;`

//instead of 'D:\T1.dbf' put the path and name of your deleted DBF file.

4-`alter database open;`

Done! As you know your data is gone but your database is ready to use.

Answer (score 2):

As it appears you are on a Windows machine from the format of the file "D:\T1.DBF". If you deleted the file from Windows Explorer it should be in the Recyclebin where it can be restored and your database subsequently opened.

If you deleted (dropped) the datafile from SQL then you are out of luck since you have stated you have no backups.

Comment: Either you have a backup, the data file is in the recycle bin or you just have to rebuild what you had. What kind of data is in that table space? If it was a new data file that did not yet have data, it might be possible to get at the data in the other data files. But you need to think about creating a backup and recovery plan.

Answer (score 1):

If you added a new data file as a part of a new table space and there is no data in this table space, then you should be able to offline drop the table space and get the database open without losing anything else. But before you try anything you need to do a cold backup. Run "select name from v$datafile order by 1;" as sys, and shutdown the database, then make a copy of any directory that has datafiles. You should also do "show parameter control_files". Then you can try "ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '' OFFLINE FOR DROP;" and "alter database open resetlogs;" which might work. But at least you start with a cold backup.

Comment: I tried this unfortunetly didn't work.